# How to change php version (runtime) in App Engine on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, version, google-app-engine-php

I created an application in App Engine on Google Cloud Platform. It uses PHP 5.5 by default. I can see it in app.yaml:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
```

How can I change to php 7.2? I haven't found any information in google documentation on that.

Comment: You need flexible environment i.e `env: flex`, then check the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7.2 is currently Beta in App Engine Standard. So use the directive

```
runtime: php72
```

See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime